# jQuery put a div on hidden, put another div around it with class and css

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put a existing div on hidden, and then add my own div around that one and add custom css to it in jQuery. It must all be in the script, since the script loads before any other css.

This is what i got so far.

```
var div  = inputElement.parent();

div.css("visibility", "hidden");

/* How do I append a <div> with class filterStylingBasic, with the given css */ 
div.append("<div>");

div.attr('class', 'myclass_'+colorInfo.name);
div.css("background-color", colorInfo.colorCode);

div.addClass('filterStylingBasic');

div.css("width", "20px");
div.css("height", "20px");
div.css("display", "inline-block");
div.css("marginLeft", "5px");
div.css("marginBottom", "5px");
div.css("pointerEvents", "auto");
div.css("cursor", "pointer");
```

Comment: try to put new div with all this css and make it hidden and then append to current div dynamically. rather than writing these many lines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your existing code, you are manipulation the `CSS` properties of existing `div` element.

You need to create the `DIV` element then append the newly created element to existing `div`

```
var newDiv = $("<div></div>", {
    'class': 'myclass_'+colorInfo.name
})
.css({
    "background-color" : colorInfo.colorCode,
    "width" : "20px", //Rest of the properties
})
.addClass('filterStylingBasic');

//Append to div
div.append(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways:

#### 1

```
var div2 = $('<div class="filterStylingBasic">');
div.append(div2);
```

#### 2

```
var div2 = $('<div>');
div2.addClass('filterStylingBasic');
div.append(div2);
```